# How to plot histogram of mean of one column while bins are defined by another column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I want to plot a histogram for two columns of my Pandas DataFrame.

Bins are defined on a `ratio` column, e.g. [0-0.1, 0.1-0.2,...,0.9-1.0], and I want to plot the mean value of another column called `feet` for each bin.

Is there a way to just plot the histogram without generating a new column ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to create a new column, just pass a function to groupby:

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'ratio':np.random.rand(100), 'feet': np.random.rand(100)*10})
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.ratio, np.linspace(0,1,11))).feet.mean().plot.bar()
```

[image]
PS: Starting with version 1.1.0 of pandas you can directly specify the y label like `...plot.bar(ylabel='Mean feet')`.

Comment: I actually came back here to reverse my edit and see your comment which I completely agree with - my apologies! (and I'm a little embarrassed)

Comment: @zelusp: don't worry, no problem